# Blank cells in Excel when converted to tabbed index

Tags: excel, csv

When i convert Excel Sheet data into tabbed delimited the blank cells are not considered, which creates a problem in my java program. When i insert garbage value my program runs properly. hence i need a proper method in which i can deal with the blank cells. If there is a tool it will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: You can manually put a placeholder value in all the blank cells in Excel, and then in Java replace that placeholder with "" or null.

Steps:
1. To quickly grab all blank cells, use your mouse to select the range of cells that you want to import and then press CTRL+G on a PC (or Edit > Special > GoTo on a Mac) and then select "Blank Cells".  You will then have all your blank cells selected.

2. Type in your placeholder value such as "placeholder123" and then press CTRL+ENTER on a PC (or CMD+ENTER on a Mac?).  Then the value will be entered in all selected (formerly blank) cells.
3. In your Java program, ignore all imported values that say "placeholder123".

Does that work for you?

Comment: That helped, but i am still quizzed why don't thy add some functionality to tackel this problem.

Comment: Also, you may try a different delimiter than the tab character.  You may find that the tab character was invisible, so it looked like nothing was happening, but that it was working fine.  So using a different visible delimiter like a "," or "|" may show you that the blank cells were there the whole time.

Comment: problem wit , and | is that there are some field as "AX|1080, New"